# Geoserver WMS layers not generated as tree structure in MapFish PDF

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, web-mapping, printing, mapfish

I am using the MapFish printing module in my web map application.In that everything is working fine but layers not generated as tree structure in output PDF file and "ODC_Graphics_Data" wms layer not printed.  I have used below code to generate pdf.

System: Windows XP / Tomcat7 / Geoserver 2.4.0/printing-2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

How do I fix this?

```
  http://localhost:8080/geoserver/pdf/print.pdf?spec={
  "layout":"A3 portrait",
  "srs":"EPSG:404000",
  "units":"m",
  "dpi":300,
  "outputFilename": "ggg",
  "layers":[
    {
        "baseURL":"http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8080/geoserver/cite/wms",
        "opacity":1,
        "singleTile":false,
        "type":"WMS",
        "layers":["Oxford_Map"],
        "format":"image/png",
        "styles":[],
        "overview":true
    },
    {
        "baseURL":"http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8080/geoserver/cite/wms",
        "opacity":1,
        "singleTile":true,
        "customParams":{"CQL_FILTER": "User_id = 234"},
        "type":"WMS",
        "layers":["ODC_Graphics_Data"],
        "format":"image/png",
        "styles":[],
        "overview":false
    },
    {   
        "baseURL":"http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8080/geoserver/cite/wms",
        "opacity":1,
        "singleTile":true,
        "type":"WMS",
        "layers":["Plymouth_Buildings"],
        "format":"image/png",
        "styles":[],
        "overview":false
    },
    {
        "baseURL":"http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8080/geoserver/cite/wms",
        "opacity":1,
        "singleTile":true,
        "type":"WMS",
        "layers":["Plymouth_Hard_Surface_Block_Paving"],
        "format":"image/png",
        "styles":[],
        "overview":false
    },
    {
        "baseURL":"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms",
        "opacity":1,
        "singleTile":true,
        "type":"WMS",
        "layers":["Plymouth_QUERIES"],
        "format":"image/png",
        "styles":[],
        "overview":false
    },
    {
        "baseURL":"http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8080/geoserver/cite/wms",
        "opacity":1,
        "singleTile":true,
        "type":"WMS",
        "layers":["Plymouth_Street_Lights"],
        "format":"image/png","styles":[],
        "overview":false
    }
],
 "pages":[
    {
        "center":[248744.93342196,55350.945],
        "mapTitle":"",
        "company":"testuser2_portrait",
        "comment":"",
        "scale":439,
        "rotation":0
    }
] }
```

Please find screenshot for output PDF:
[image]
[image]